# Static utility methods to CDI (Weld JEE6)

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld, weld

I have a simple old style static methods in a utility class. I am struggling to "CDI" it due to the paramterised objects required each time..any help appreciated on how best to approach this?

i.e. i would like to Inject the utility class into multiple classes and call the methods below (and similar) where required...The utility class would in turn inject the ByteArrayInputStream,ObjectInputStream each time with correct parameters...

Old class:

```
public class Utils {


      public static Object fromByteArray(final byte[] data) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

                final ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                final ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
                return o.readObject();
      }


      public static byte[] toByteArray(final MyObj tx)  throws IOException{
                final ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                final ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
                o.writeObject(tx);
                return b.toByteArray();
      }

}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. Two possibilities:

Simply use this in the method/constructor of your bean:

```
Object object = Utils.fromByteArray(...);
```

Inject it:

```
@Inject
private Utils utils;
```

You don't need to modify your class `Utils` at all.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. the above answer works. As there are no constructors, this is actually a CDI bean already, just dependent scoped, which since there isn't any state doesn't matter. You can inject and call as needed. You could use events as well.

Comment: @LightGuard So there actually isn't any scope needed? I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Nope, you don't need a scope. By default, meaning without any scope declared, beans are Dependent, which means they'll be created and instrumented then injected into the containing bean, and be like any other field, lasting until the containing bean is destroyed.